The React app is not being hosted on AWS EC2 using nginx
I have built a serverless static react app with Vite.
I created an AWS EC2 instance
I set up security groups
Installed npm, node, nginx
setup nginx
I tried to access the website with the EC2 IP and it was hosted.
The problem occurred when I stopped the EC2 instance and restarted it.
Now my website is no more hosted, I tried to check the status of nginx using service nginx status and its status was "started a high-performance web server..."
When I am trying to access the IP of my EC2 instance it is not showing me any result.
I tried to restart the EC2 instance and was expecting to see the website using its IP.

When you stop and start an ec2 instance with public ip, it's public ip will be changed. Additional note: if you just restart the ec2 (it have separate api) its public ip will remain same. Maybe that is your problem.

I have used elastic IP for getting a static IP address and this fixed my issue.
Thanks for advice
